# How to get file in Silverlight Application?

Tags: silverlight, url, web

Suppose, we have a sivlerlight application - SLApp. SLApp is located on the WebSite someweb.com. Link on file likes this - someweb.com/SLApp?URL="https://smthg.com/file.exe" .
How to get this file in the silverlight app&

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand what you want from your question:

For getting a file from the client machine and sending it to the server:
You can't do that directly, it's a security risk, and hence disabled.  You can only access files via the file open dialog.

For getting a file from the server to the client:
Now if you are wanting to download a file to the client via a link, then you can just open a web page with the link/url, that way you use the standard browser functionality.